# jqGrid edit form prefills by wrong values. (On second time clicked)

Tags: jqgrid, edit, subgrid

I use jqGrid plugin. There are grid and sub grid turned on. When I click second time to edit row from main grid then fields populates by wrong value.
Detailed steps to reproduce:

1. Click edit row (main grid row)
2. Edit form populated correctly, ok (see first screen)
3. Click 'Cancel' button
4. Click edit row again
5. Edit form populated wrong (see second screen)

Here is my code:

```
$(function () {
        $("#list").jqGrid({
            url: 'Country/CountryListPaged',
            editurl: "Country/AddEditDeleteCountry",
            datatype: "json",
            mtype: 'POST',
            colModel: [
                          { name: 'idCountry', index: 'idCountry', label: 'Id', width: 100, editable:true, hidden:true },
                          { name: 'code', index: 'code', label: 'Код', width: 200, align:'center', editable: true, edittype:'text', editrules:{ required:true} },
                          { name: 'title', index: 'title', label: 'Название', width: 300, align: 'center', editable: true, edittype: 'text', editrules: { required: true} }
                      ],
            pager: '#pager',
            rowNum: 10,
            rowList: [10, 20],
            sortname: 'Title',
            sortorder: 'desc',
            viewrecords: true,
            gridview: true,
            caption: 'Список стран',
            height: 'auto',
            autowidth: true,
            scrollOffset: 0,
            hidegrid: false,
            subGrid: true,
            subGridRowExpanded: function (subgridId, rowId) {
                var subgridTableId, pagerId;
                subgridTableId = subgridId + "_t";
                pagerId = "p_" + subgridTableId;
                var tmp = $("#list").getRowData(rowId);
                var idCountry = tmp.idCountry;
                var countryCode = tmp.code;

                $("#" + subgridId).html("<table id='" + subgridTableId + "' class='scroll'></table><div id='" + pagerId + "' class='scroll'></div>");
                jQuery("#" + subgridTableId).jqGrid({
                    url: "Country/CountryTranslateVariantsList?idCountry=" + idCountry + "&countryCode=" + countryCode,
                    editurl: "Country/AddEditDeleteCountryTranslateVariant",
                    mtype: "POST",
                    datatype: "json",
                    colModel: [{ name: "idCountryTranslate", index: "IdCountryTranslate", editable: true, hidden: true },
                               { name: "countryTranslateCode", index: "countryTranslateCode", editable: true, hidden: true, edittype: "text", editoptions: { defaultValue: countryCode} },
                               { name: "language", index: "Language", label: "Язык", width: 100, editable: true, edittype: "select", editoptions: { value: "en:en;ru:ru;fr:fr;de:de" }, editrules: { required: true} },
                               { name: "countryTranslateTitle", index: "countryTranslateTitle", label: "Название", width: 180, editable: true, editrules: { required: true}}],
                    rowNum: 5,
                    pager: pagerId,
                    sortname: 'language',
                    sortorder: "asc",
                    viewrecords: true,
                    gridview: true,
                    height: '100%'
                });
                //SUB GRID NAVIGATION PANEL
                jQuery("#" + subgridTableId).jqGrid('navGrid', "#" + pagerId,
                                                        { edit: true, add: true, del: true, search: false, refresh: false },
                                                        {mtype: "POST", closeAfterEdit: true, reloadAfterSubmit: true }, //edit parameters
                                                        {mtype: "POST", closeAfterAdd: true, reloadAfterSubmit: true }, //add parameters
                                                        {mtype: "POST", reloadAfterSubmit: true, serializeDelData: function (postdata) {
                                                            var rowdata = $("#" + subgridTableId).getRowData(postdata.id);
                                                            return { oper: postdata.oper, idCountryTranslate: rowdata.idCountryTranslate };
                                                        }
                                                    }, //delete parameters
                                                        {}//search parameteres
                                                        );
            }
        });
        //MAIN GRID NAVIGATION PANEL
        jQuery("#list").jqGrid('navGrid', "#pager",
                    { edit: true, add: true, del: true, search: false, refresh: true },
                    { mtype: "POST", closeAfterEdit: true, reloadAfterSubmit: true }, //edit parameters
                    {mtype: "POST", closeAfterAdd: true, reloadAfterSubmit: true }, //add parameters
                    {mtype: "POST", reloadAfterSubmit: true, serializeDelData: function (postdata) {
                        var rowdata = $("#list").getRowData(postdata.id);
                        return { oper: postdata.oper, idCountry: rowdata.idCountry };
                    }
                }, //delete parameters
                    {}//search parameteres
                    );
    }); 
</script>
<div style="margin:10px auto auto auto;width:100%;height:100%;">
    <table id="list">
        <tr>
            <td/>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <div id="pager"></div>
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: the problem can't be reproduce with the information which you posted. See [here](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/Yara.htm). You should post the test data additionally.

Comment: You mean json ? If yes, then for the main grid I have next json {"page":1,"total":1,"records":2,"rows":[{"cell":["8","ukr","Украина"]},{"cell":["9","rus","Russia"]}]}, and for sub grid I have next json: {"page":1,"total":1,"records":3,"rows":[{"cell":["21","ukr","ru","Украина"]},{"cell":["22","ukr","en","Ukraine"]},{"cell":["23","ukr","fr","Ukraine"]}]}

Answer (score 0):

I found the reason. "grid.subgrid.js" file was included and it caused problem. Oleg, thank you for response.